# How to use librt function in Python?

Tags: python, c, linux, shared-libraries, perforce

I'm trying to use a third-party .so, P4API.so, that calls clock_gettime defined in librt.so and would like users of my script not to have to set LD_PRELOAD. So in the **init**.py file, I have:

```
import ctypes

librt = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('librt.so')
```

This loads the library fine, but running the script still emits:

```
ImportError: /path/to/P4API.so: undefined symbol: clock_gettime
```

I've tried:

```
__builtins__['clock_gettime'] = librt.clock_gettime
```

but that doesn't work, either.

How can I get P4API.so to recognize the loaded librt?

Comment: But why does P4API.so not link with `librt.so` on its own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load it with

```
 ctypes.CDLL('librt.so', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

in order to make it available to other libraries.